# Debugging Oracle Triggers using PL\SQL Developer 7.0.2?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper

I am able to debug the procedures and functions in PL\SQL Developer but when i set break points for Trigger its not taking them as a valid break points. Can we debug code in triggers using pl\sql developer.

Comment: I put some DML in a test window, add break points to the trigger and it works for me. How do you do it ? what goes wrong when you try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As A.B.Cade said I just put some DML in a test window, added break points to the trigger and it worked. But prior to that we have to right click on trigger and select "Add Debug information" on context menu.